# Angular app is not running on (Ubuntu) digitalocean server?

Tags: angular, deployment, digital-ocean

I uploaded my angular app distributed file to a server now i am trying to run angular app on a server but its not working.

When I try `ng-serve` on a putty (app) on my dist folder i get this blank output and nothing is happening (see the picture below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiNdw.jpg)

I also uploaded my anglar backend (node app) and for that when I run `npm start` is working fine.

if someone know how fix it please let me know and by the way i am absolute beginner to all of this and this is my first time to digitalocean and angular app deployment... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must verify the Angular CLI version in your server by using **ng version** command. If you haven't installed CLI you must install it **npm install -g @angular/cli** . Otherwise, you can use **npm start** for the angular app as well